# How to create a confirm dialog component with React

Tags: reactjs

How to create a confirm dialogue function which returns `true` or `false`

I don't want to pass callback function as props

I want to access the function like this

```js
import { deleteConfirm } from 'ConfirmDialog'

const deleteItem = () => {
  if (deleteConfirm('Are you sure?')) {
  }
}
```

I expect a confirmation modal opened, having two buttons, 'yes' or 'no'
On clicking the button above function will receive value

Comment: React components return jsx, not booleans. What are you trying to achieve? Passing callback functions as props is exactly how you *should* do it.

Comment: Can you please post all of the code? We have no idea what parameters deleteConfirm accepts.

Comment: In the above code deleteConfirm is a function, not a react component, but when we call it, a modal should popup(a react component) for user input. the deleteConfirm function will then return the user input